# Solution for this complex ACL requirement in Silex/Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, authorization, acl, silex

I want to implement ACL for my product which has groups (company, department,...), users and objects. The rules are following:

(Note: manage = view + create + edit + delete)

- System staffs (lower than admins and higher than users) can create system users, group users but not system staffs/admins.
- A group admins can manage members (users & admins) of the group
- A group members (users & admins) can manage objects of the group

Assuming: User table contains **group_id** & Object table contains **user_id**

Can I use (and extend if needed) Symfony ACL to do so? If yes, how? If not, any suggestion/solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at security voters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html They are much easier to implement than acls's.  And I think they can implement your rules.

Comment: Yes, Voter would be fine when permission layer need not to be dynamic. For my case, I need the permission to be stored in db so that Super Admin can assign any action to any role. I don't see voter helping me unless I store permissions manually and fetch them while deciding inside voter callback. @michael, If you find anything, please do share. :)